# Flutter - InkResponse on a Custom Button

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to create that button with a gradient and that exact disposition. As I couldn't use the `RaisedButton`, I had to recreate one from scratch. Everything is perfect except one thing : I don't have the Ink response that I have with the RaisedButton. I thought that adding the `InkResponse` widget in the tree would make it, but it doesn't do anything :/

[image]

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      elevation: 7.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
      child: InkResponse(
        child: Ink(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: gradient,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
          ),
          child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 48),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                SizedBox(width: 48),
                Expanded(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      text,
                      style: MC_callToActionGradientText,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 48.0,
                  child: Icon(
                    icon,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 23.0,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: use InkWell instate of InkResponse

Comment: I tried as well but it still doesn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide some kind of callback to InkResponse in order for splashes to be visible, e.g. `onTap`, `onLongPress` etc. But it looks weird if you do it like that, as @Tipu mentioned, in this case its easier to just use InkWell. It would look something like that:

```dart
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      elevation: 7.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Ink(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.pink]),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
          ),
          height: 48,
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              SizedBox(width: 48),
              Expanded(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Hello",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 48.0,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.send,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 23.0,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, I didn't know that it wouldn't be visible until the onTap parameter would be filled. Thanks !